# Long url doesn’t break in theorem optional argument (under amsthm, hyperref, xurl)

Tags: line-breaking, theorems, urls, amsthm, xurl

In most situations, the `xurl` package (presented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407368/1635)) ensures that long urls break across lines appropriately. However, inside the optional “caption” argument of a theorem, long urls stay unbroken, as seen in the MWE below.  **Is there a way to get them breaking automatically even there?**

My document uses `amsthm` and `hyperref`; the MWE uses `xurl`, but that’s not otherwise required in my document.  The question [Enable line breaks in captions of theorem environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558861/enable-line-breaks-in-captions-of-theorem-environment) is similar, but doesn’t cover urls (it’s for breaking long theorem captions of ordinary text, and is solved by using `amsthm`).

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{textwidth=100mm}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[1]
\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696129/long-url-doesn-t-break-in-theorem-optional-argument-under-amsthm-hyperref-xur}.
\blindtext[1]

\begin{theorem}[\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696129/long-url-doesn-t-break-in-theorem-optional-argument-under-amsthm-hyperref-xur}]
  \blindtext[1]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try with the solution in the other answer?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Which other answer do you mean in particular?  The [first linked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407368/1635) has many answers — I tried most of them, all the ones that looked applicable.  The [second linked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558861/) has just one answer — “use `amsthm`” — and I am already using that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the url is math. The theorem code stores the optional argument in a box that it then unwraps later but TeX performs some optimization in this case and omits the implicite penalties. You can try the `setouterhbox` package:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{textwidth=100mm}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{setouterhbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\section{unpatched}

$a=b=c=d=a=b=c=d=a=b=c=d=a=b=c=d=a=b=c=d=a=b=c=d=a=b=c=d=$

\begin{theorem}[$a=b=c=d=a=b=c=d=a=b=c=d=a=b=c=d=a=b=c=d=a=b=c=d=a=b=c=d=$]
 some text
\end{theorem}


\begin{theorem}[\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696129/long-url-doesn-t-break-in-theorem-optional-argument-under-amsthm-hyperref-xur}]
 some text
\end{theorem}

\section{patched}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\deferred@thm@head{\sbox\@labels{\normalfont#1}}{\setouterhbox\@labels \normalfont#1\endsetouterhbox}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{theorem}[$a=b=c=d=a=b=c=d=a=b=c=d=a=b=c=d=a=b=c=d=a=b=c=d=a=b=c=d=$]
 some text
\end{theorem}


\begin{theorem}[\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696129/long-url-doesn-t-break-in-theorem-optional-argument-under-amsthm-hyperref-xur}]
 some text
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic — this exactly fixes the issue!

Answer (score 3):

You are under no obligation to use the optional argument of the `theorem` environment to place the URL string.

[image]

This approach will have to be modified if the URL string contains certain TeX-special characters, such as `%` or `#`. In such cases, I'd recommend going the `\urldef` route, which is explained in sectin 2 of the user guide of the `url` package, "Defining a defined-url". That, or just replace `\myurl{...}` with `\begingroup\upshape(\url{...})\endgroup`.

---

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[textwidth=100mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% \usepackage{amsthm} % 'amsthm' is loaded automatically by 'amsart' doc. class
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\newcommand\myurl[1]{\begingroup\upshape(\url{#1})\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem} 
\myurl{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696129/long-url-doesn-t-break-in-theorem-optional-argument-under-amsthm-hyperref-xur}
\lipsum[1][1-5] % filler text
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I’ve accepted [@ UlrikeFisher’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/696193/1635) as it fixes the question asked, but thanks for this too, as a good very simple workaround giving very nearly the same output.